# vb.net - Error executing JavaScript

Tags: vb.net, shared-libraries

I want to execute JS code using vb.net but I'm getting error **'ScriptManager' is not a member of 'UI**.

`System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "Script", "function();", True)`

ScriptManager **is** part of *UI*, which is part of *System.Web*. I have imported *System.Web* dll, but the error still remains.

I've also tried `System.Web.UI.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Script", "function();", True)`, but it returns error **Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference**.

Am I missing something...?

Edit: I'm using **Net Framework 4**

Answer (score 0):

try doing it is to use the `ClientScriptManager:`

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    Me, Me.GetType(), "Script", "function();", True);
```

**try below sample example**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update Time" runat="server" OnClick="UpdateTime" />
<asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateTime(time) {
        document.getElementById("<%=lblTime.ClientID %>").innerHTML = time;
    }
</script>


Protected Sub UpdateTime(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim time As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
    Dim script As String = "window.onload = function() { UpdateTime('" & time & "'); };"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "UpdateTime", script, True)
End Sub
```